# Displaying a warning box on pages generated by python-sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How to display a warning box in the html generated using the `sphinx-build`?

```
Warning

Do not use the directives sectnum, header and footer.
```

I want to show the above message as something like this:
[image: image of warning message in box] (apologies, SO doesn't allow me to embed the image in the post here)
Please ignore the text formatting, my main aim to show a box with some text to get the attention of the user [like on sphinx-doc site](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#directives)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reStructuredText syntax you want is for things called [admonition directives](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#directives).

That specific example exists in the [documentation source](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blame/master/doc/usage/restructuredtext/basics.rst#L386-L389):

```
.. warning::

   Do *not* use the directives :dudir:`sectnum`, :dudir:`header` and
   :dudir:`footer`.
```

Comment: I am not sure but I get a box that only has `warning` in it and outside of the bos I get the warning message. Example image: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/647d7765dfc86ca59dff6a4992757574#gistcomment-3236976

Comment: @alper you can use [custom CSS](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files) to style the HTML markup as you like.